# Change CSS of element selected by class

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a bit of code to check if the URL of the site is a specific brand name, and then to change the colors of CSS styles depending on the brand. This is what I've got so far:

```
<?php
$URL = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if (strpos($URL, 'brandName') !== false){
    echo "<script>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function () {
            var navbar = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-default');
              for(i=0; i<navbar.length; i++) {
                navbar[i].style.border-bottom = '#ff6600 solid 5px';
              } 
        } );
    </script>";
}
?>
```

I keep getting back the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

and I'm not really sure what's wrong.

Comment: `border-bottom` is not a valid JS object property identifier. You use `borderBottom` as a substitute for CSS properties.

Comment: ...nicer to update style by using classes, IMO. CSS: `.someClass{border-bottom: #ff6600 solid 5px}` ...JS: `navbar[i].classList.add("someClass")`

Comment: If you're already using jQuery then why not use the jQuery selector and `.css` ? e.g. `$(".navbar-default").each(function() { $(this).css({"border-bottom" : "5px solid #f60"}) });`

Comment: Thanks Squint. Never would have noticed the border bottom thing. Didn't know it was different. @CD001 - I was looking up code that others had built,  this seems faster and easier, thanks, I'll switch to the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of neatness - assuming this is in a "view" type file. It's far easier to read if you break out of PHP before getting into the JS:

```
<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'brandName') !== false): ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navbar-default").each(
        $(this).css({"border-bottom" : "5px solid #f60"});
    );
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

PHP provides an alternative `<?php if(): ?> ... <?php endif: ?>` syntax ideally for templates.